# How to implement multiple developer teams (vendor branches) in Sitecore?

Tags: solution-architecture

- We have a multiple site solution in 7.2 with 7 site collections (each collection is based on a set of templates & components) with up to 20 sites in each collection.
- We want to establish a second development team that will develop components for integration into a future site (which will be built as a V2 of an existing site).
- The components will be pulling non-Sitecore data but need to be wrapped for Sitecore. The aim is for the original vendor to build the site framework, with the new vendor producing fully complete presentation components for editors to place.
- There are no major issues regarding code visibility (vendor 1 is external and has built our solution, vendor 2 is internal), except that data access and business logic of the new components may need to be delivered pre-compiled.
- Vendor 1 will continue developing features and maintaining the solution across all site collections, while vendor two will only be delivering for a specific site.
- Vendor 1 works on a bi-weekly sprint, vendor 2 may want to have considerably longer cycles between releases.

How should this be set up in order to ensure minimum hassle with merges, data synch etc. and to delineate vendor responsibility?
I'm particularly interested in the architecture and processes that would be needed to support this.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very broad question as there are many ways you can achieve that not only with Sitecore implementation but in general. Honestly I don't think you will get everything you need from this answer but I'll add my 2 cents. You should have an architect helping you stablish what it takes to get that done. 
From my perspective I would say you need at least two things to help you address that:

1- source control. (Git, TFS, etc). Also you will need to stablish process for merges and releases accross teams that someone owns it. For example, each team work on separate branches and you have an integration branch where someone is responsible for making sure that whatever gets there works for everyone. This is just one example

2- I highly recommend that you use tools to help source control sitecore items like Unicorn or TDS from Hedgegog.I have more experience with TDS so I'll speak about this one: with TDS you can not only source control your sitecore database but you can use it to stablish deployments across environenments (CI, DEV, QA, UAT, PROD).

hope this helps